# Modifying a table

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

[image]

created by:

```
\documentclass[11pt,french]{book}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage
[
        a4paper,
        left=1cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm
]
{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Outils numériques}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence)  & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline
Outils numériques 2  &  $\rm PC^{(1)}$ (L3)  & $\rm TD^{(5)}$ &   4\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Enseignements de physique}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline

Thermodynamique &  PC (L1)  & $\rm CM^{(4)}$,$\rm TD$   & 61.25 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
$\rm TP^{(6)}$ de physique &  PC (L1)  & $\rm TP$ & 90 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique & PC (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique&  $\rm SVT^{(2)}$ (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 Mécanique du point & PC (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Autres enseignements}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline
Transfert thermique & Pro. $\rm EE^{(3)}$ (L3)  & $\rm CM$,$\rm TD$   & 18 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption[Inventaire des enseignements dispensés (ATER--(2016-2017, UAPV)]{\label{tableauens}Récapitulatif des heures (ATER--(2016-2017, UAPV) 
\begin{itemize}
\item[] {\small \textbf{(1) : Physique-Chimie} $||$ \small \textbf{(2) : Sciences de la Vie et de la Terre} $||$ \textbf{(3) : Efficacité Énergétique}}
\item[] {\small \textbf{(4) : cours magistraux} $||$ \textbf{(5) : travaux dirigés} $||$ \textbf{(6) : travaux pratiques}}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

How can I increase the padding between  the rows inside the `multicolum` environment?

Also how can the contens of the cells of the second and the fifth line be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: Some of your LaTeX coding habits are, shall we say, unusual. I suggest you engage less in visual formatting and make more use of standard LaTeX packages, such as `threeparttable`, to structure and streamline the table-related code. Also, don't over-use **boldfacing** for emphasis -- unless you want to come across as **shouting all the time**.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\def\arraystretch{1.25}

\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Outils numériques}} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence)  & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline
Outils numériques 2  &  PC\textsuperscript{(1)}\ (L3)  & TD\textsuperscript{(5)} &   4\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Enseignements de physique}} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline
Thermodynamique &  PC (L1)  & CM\textsuperscript{(4)}{}, TD   & 61.25 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
TP\textsuperscript{(6)}\ de physique &  PC (L1)  & TP & 90 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique & PC (L1)  & Tutorat & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique&  SVT\textsuperscript{(2)}\ (L1)  & Tutorat & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 Mécanique du point & PC (L1)  Tutorat & 6 & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Autres enseignements}} \\
\hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\
\hline
Transfert thermique & Pro.\ EE\textsuperscript{(3)}\ (L3)  & CM, TD  & 18 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[(1)] Physique-Chimie
\item[(2)] Sciences de la Vie et de la Terre
\item[(3)] Efficacité Énergétique
\item[(4)] cours magistraux
\item[(5)] travaux dirigés
\item[(6)] travaux pratiques
\end{tablenotes}

\caption{\label{tableauens}Récapitulatif des heures (ATER--(2016--2017), UAPV)}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

The `\def\arraystretch{0.8}` command renders the table rows too close. Besides, it should be `\renewcommand` and not `\def`. For centering row cells vertically, use the `m` column type from `array` package instead of `p`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,french]{book}    
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,array}    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\bgroup
%\def\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{3cm}|p{2.5cm}|m{2cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Outils numériques}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\    \hline
Matière & Public (Licence)  & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\    \hline
Outils numériques 2  &  $\rm PC^{(1)}$ (L3)  & $\rm TD^{(5)}$ &   4\\  \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Enseignements de physique}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\    \hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\    \hline    
Thermodynamique &  PC (L1)  & $\rm CM^{(4)}$,$\rm TD$   & 61.25 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
$\rm TP^{(6)}$ de physique &  PC (L1)  & $\rm TP$ & 90 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique & PC (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 De l'électricité à la mécanique&  $\rm SVT^{(2)}$ (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\
%- -&- -&- -&- -\\
 Mécanique du point & PC (L1)  & $\rm Tutorat$ & 6 \\    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \textbf{Autres enseignements}} \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\    \hline
Matière & Public (Licence) & Type & Heures (Eq.~TD)\\    \hline
Transfert thermique & Pro. $\rm EE^{(3)}$ (L3)  & $\rm CM$,$\rm TD$   & 18 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption[Inventaire des enseignements dispensés (ATER--(2016-2017, UAPV)]{\label{tableauens}Récapitulatif des heures (ATER--(2016-2017, UAPV) 
\begin{itemize}
\item[] {\small \textbf{(1) : Physique-Chimie} $||$ \small \textbf{(2) : Sciences de la Vie et de la Terre} $||$ \textbf{(3) : Efficacité Énergétique}}
\item[] {\small \textbf{(4) : cours magistraux} $||$ \textbf{(5) : travaux dirigés} $||$ \textbf{(6) : travaux pratiques}}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```